# io.BufferedReader peek function returning all the text in the buffer

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.4.1 on Windows 8.

I would like to read a file with a buffered interface that allows me to peek a certain number of bytes ahead as well reading bytes. [`io.BufferedReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader) seems like the right choice.

Unfortunately, `io.BufferReader.peek` seems useless because it appears to just return all the bytes stored in the buffer, rather than the number requested. In fact, this is allowed by the documentation of this function (emphasis mine):

> peek([size]) Return bytes from the stream without advancing the
> position. At most one single read on the raw stream is done to satisfy
> the call. The number of bytes returned may be **less or more** than
> requested.

To demonstrate what I consider useless behaviour, I have the following test file called `Test1.txt`:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

I create the `io.BufferedReader` object like this in IDLE:

```
>>> stream = io.BufferedReader(io.FileIO('Test1.txt'))
```

and then ask for **two** bytes,

```
>>> stream.peek(2)
b'first line\r\nsecond line\r\nthird line'
```

Eh? That's just all the text in the default buffer size (which is 8192 bytes on my system). If I change this default, I can confirm that `peek()` is just returning the contents of the buffer,

```
>>> stream2 = io.BufferedReader(io.FileIO('Test1.txt'), buffer_size=2)
>>> stream2.peek(17)
b'fi'
>>> stream2.peek(17)
b'fi'
>>> stream2.read(2)
b'fi'
>>> stream2.peek(17)
b'rs'
```

To be clear, the following is the output *I expect to see*:

```
>>> stream = io.BufferedReader(io.FileIO('Test1.txt'))
>>> stream.peek(2)
b'fi'
>>> stream.read(1)
b'f'
>>> stream.peek(2)
b'ir'
```

That is, a typical buffered stream.

What am I doing wrong in constructing this `BufferedReader`? How can I observe the behaviour I expect to see in Python 3.4.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.peek()` is indeed implemented as returning the current buffer; if you combined it with `.read()` calls you'd find that less and less of the buffer is returned until the buffer is filled up again.

For most purposes of `.peek()` this is more than fine. The number of bytes lets you limit how much data is expected from the underlying I/O source if the buffer is empty, which in turn is important if that source blocks on reads.

Simply slice the returned value:

```
stream.peek(num)[:num]
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: why does `.peek()` take a number of bytes to read at all then? The number of bytes to read doesn't seem to have a use if all the function does is return whatever is in the internal buffer.

Comment: @wrtmu: the same interface can be used for network sockets and any other I/O too, where the availability of the buffer may depend on the number of bytes actually available to read.

Comment: @wrtmu: Basically, the number of bytes is passed to an internal read call if there is no buffered data, that's where the limits come into play.