# Python: why does peek(1) return 8K bytes instead of 1 byte?

Tags: python, file-io, peek

I'm using Python 3, and the peek() method for buffered file I/O doesn't seem to work as documented. For example, the following code illustrates the problem -- it prints **8192** as the length of the byte string returned by `f.peek(1)`:

```
jpg_file = 'DRM_1851.JPG'
with open(jpg_file, 'rb') as f:
    next_byte = f.peek(1)
    print(len(next_byte))
```

I sometimes want to peek at the next byte without moving the file pointer, but since the above doesn't work I'm doing something this in those places instead:

```
next_byte = f.read(1) # read a byte
f.seek(-1,1) # move the file pointer back one byte
```

That works, but feels like a kludge. Am I misunderstanding something about how peek() works?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474687/io-bufferedreader-peek-function-returning-all-the-text-in-the-buffer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader.peek):

> **peek([size])**
>
> Return bytes from the stream without advancing the position. At most one single read on the raw stream is done to satisfy the call. **The number of bytes returned may be less or more than requested.**

Emphasis mine.

Since the file pointer isn't moved in `peek`, it doesn't really matter if `peek` reads more than the amount you want. Just take a substring after you peek: `next_byte = f.peek(1)[:1]`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `f.peek(1)[:1]` in case there are no bytes returned?

Comment: Thanks much! I understand now. I have to admit, I've read that line in the Python docs more than once and I never fully internalized those three words "or more than."