# Tensorflow Removing JFIF

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am quite new to tensorflow, I would like to clearly know, what does the below command do?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import os

num_skipped = 0
for folder_name in ("Cat", "Dog"):
    print("folder_name:",folder_name) #folder_name: Cat
    folder_path = os.path.join("Dataset/PetImages", folder_name)
    print("folder_path:",folder_path) #folder_path: Dataset/PetImages/Cat
    for fname in os.listdir(folder_path):
        print("fname:",fname) #fname: 5961.jpg
        fpath = os.path.join(folder_path, fname)
        print("fpath:", fpath) #fpath: Dataset/PetImages/Cat/10591.jpg
        try:
            fobj = open(fpath, "rb")
            is_jfif = tf.compat.as_bytes("JFIF") in fobj.peek(10)
        finally:
            fobj.close()

        if not is_jfif:
            num_skipped += 1
            # Delete corrupted image
            os.remove(fpath)

print("Deleted %d images" % num_skipped)
```

**Keras Website comment on the above code :**

*When working with lots of real-world image data, corrupted images are a common occurence. Let's filter out badly-encoded images that do not feature the string "JFIF" in their header.*

I want to specifically know what does the below command do, how does it do ?

```
 is_jfif = tf.compat.as_bytes("JFIF") in fobj.peek(10)
```

I checked the API but wasn't clearly able to understand it.

A better explanation will be of much help.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure) explains that JPG files contain the string "JFIF" at the beginning of the file, encoded as bytes:

[image: JFIF header]

So:

- `tf.compat.as_bytes("JFIF")` converts the string "JFIF" to bytes. You could also just use `b"JFIF"`, though maybe the TensorFlow implementation has some optimization I don't know about.
- `fobj.peek(10)` theoretically returns the first 10 bytes of the file, but in practice it often returns the [entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474687/io-bufferedreader-peek-function-returning-all-the-text-in-the-buffer).
- `is_jfif` then just checks if the converted "JFIF" string is in the result of `fobj.peek`.

Answer (score 3):

The command translates into bytes the given string (`JFIF`) and checks if it is present in the file object, at byte `10`. It's a quick that verifies content of a header.

Not my first choice when it comes to dealing with "corrupted data", normally you'd leave this to a module that knows much more about image handling. It's a tutorial though, so the focus was on the brevity and highlighting a problem, rather then providing a comprehensive solution.