# Python binary data save as png

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, amazon-sagemaker

So I've been banging my head against this for hours and I can't quite get it to work.

The file is sent as image/png and comes across in what looks like binary data if I print it.

The problem I'm getting is commented #PROBLEM HERE - essential PIL can't read the file back, it's 100% in the directory.

```
cannot identify image file '/tmp/image.jpg'
```

I tried JSON etc too and base64 but ended up in same circle, it's going to be something really silly.

I'm using Postman to test Sagemaker endpoint integration - here's my code - I'm including the lot because hopefully you see whilst this is a dumb question I've put a LOT of work into this I'm relatively new to python.

In order to make this work in Lambda I had to drag modules from both MXNet, Sagemaker, and numerous .so from the ubuntu file system and upload as part of the package so that it met the space requirements for Lambda.(End result is 100mb lambda package, which is better than the 300 I started with.)

```
sys.path.append('./libs')
from record_pb2 import Record
from recordio import MXRecordIO
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

    # event, context
    def handler(event, context):

      print(event)
      print('Body')
      # tried 'w' here too.
      with open('/tmp/image.jpg' , 'wb') as file:
        # Tried without encode and no 'b' above.
        file.write(event['body'].encode())

      files = os.listdir('/tmp')
      print(files)

      im = PIL.Image.open('/tmp/image.jpg')
      im.thumbnail([800,600],PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
      im.save('/tmp/resized.jpg', "JPEG")
      files = os.listdir('/tmp')
      print(files)


      with open('/tmp/resized.jpg', 'r') as image:
        img = image.read()
        img = bytearray(img)

      response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='ss-notebook-demo-2020-06-02-09-27-40-405',
                                          ContentType='image/jpeg',
                                          Accept='application/x-protobuf',
                                          Body=img)

      print(response)

      result = response['Body'].read()

      results_file = '/temp/results.rec'

      with open(results_file, 'wb') as f:
          f.write(result)

      rec = Record()
      recordio = MXRecordIO(results_file, 'r')
      protobuf = rec.ParseFromString(recordio.read())

      values = list(rec.features["target"].float32_tensor.values)
      shape = list(rec.features["shape"].int32_tensor.values)
      shape = np.squeeze(shape)
      mask = np.reshape(np.array(values), shape)
      mask = np.squeeze(mask, axis=0)

      pred_map = np.argmax(mask, axis=0)
      unique_elements, counts_elements = np.unique(pred_map[pred_map != 0], return_counts=True)
      #print(unique_elements, counts_elements)
      #print(pred_map[pred_map != 0].size)
      #print(np.bincount(pred_map[pred_map != 0]).argmax())

      return {
        'classes': unique_elements,
        'counts': counts_elements,
        'top': np.bincount(pred_map[pred_map != 0]).argmax(),
      }
```

For those that are interested that right there is how you get classes and pixel count PER class from a semantic segmentation recordio-protobuf in Sagemaker! :-)

Update:

Body sample, note this isn't the whole thing because it's huge.

```
'body': '����\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00��\x00C\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01��\x00C\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01��\x00\x11\x08\x07�\x05d\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01��\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b��\x00�\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142���\x08#B��\x15R��$3br�\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b��\x00�\x11\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x04\x07\x05\x04\x04\x00\x01\x02w\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x04\x05!1\x06\x12AQ\x07aq\x13"2�\x08\x14B����\t#3R�\x15br�\n\x16$4�%�\x17\x18\x19\x1a&\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00�*\x03�\n8�\x06R����\x17�vs�\x04��g\x14�)3��2�k�7�K\x029��\x1f��4<�|��I�\'heN��\x1f�^s�3�q�\x16\x17�ɘ\'�3\x1c�ّ�~G\x07ؚ�+��\x7f\x17�G%�ԓR��\x17\x7f�),!
```

Comment: Does your `'/tmp/image.png'` image file contains any bytes? Couldn't be that the image file you are trying to load is corrupted in any way? ...Are you using `Image` from `from PIL import Image` ?

Comment: Heya yeah so im = PIL.Image.open('/tmp/image.png') is where it bugs out, there's definitely binary data in that variable it's huge!

Comment: I'm not sure event['body'].encode() is right though, just hunting around.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3287

Comment: Hmm so that gives the same error but with with BytesIO stuff in it, good try though mate, somethings going wrong when it's being written by the looks of it.

Comment: @MrkFldig Hi, I am having similar difficulty in parsing application/x-recordio-protobuf. Where do you get that `record_pb2` library?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample of `body` reveals that it is a JPG file, not a PNG. That is why `PIL.Image` is refusing to open it. Change the file extension and try it again.

Comment: No way, hold on i'm testing it - it's a png on my desktop though. How did you find that out by the please buddy?

Comment: Because it has "JFIF" in the first 10 bytes. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220855/tensorflow-removing-jfif/62222665#62222665

Comment: Same error unfortunately, am I encoding it correctly when I'm writing it? Updated the code to reflect your changes.

Comment: Yeah so if I do that at take b off 'wb' I'm back to the same PIL error, tis odd.

Comment: Does it work when you try to open the file locally, without going through your event handler? According to the [JPG standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format), the first two bytes should be `\xff\xd8`, but that is not what you have right now. PIL is apparently very strict about these things even if a normal photo editor will open the file.

Comment: Hey just an update on this I figured out the problem which actually you led me to - will post back shortly.